# Visual C# source files in subdirectory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How do you get Visual C# 2010 to go along with the idea of putting source files in a subdirectory, that is, `*.cs` moves to `src\*.cs` while leaving everything else where it is? It's probably something very simple, I just tried creating a test class as `src\myclass.cs` instead of plain `myclass.cs` and Visual C# would have none of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click the project add new folder, right-click the folder add new item.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just create the class as usual and in the ProjectExplorer in VS you can move the class into a folder like in the normal explorer.

Comment: +1 Yes, dragging and dropping inside a project will initiate a move action. Dragging and dropping across projects initiates a copy.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to remember is that the directories are only for the developers purposes, once you hit compile that does not matter because all files get put into 1 root compilation.

But as both `František Žiačik` and `rwallace` said, by going to your Project Manage area to the right of your VS you will see a set of files and folders, just right click the top one to expand the right click menu and you should see `Add Item` just go in there and click folder.

Stay cool